# How to istall java in ubuntu 18.10

Tags: apt, java

```
gokulraj@optimus-prime:~$ sudo apt install default-jdk
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?
```

The error is occured.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possibilities;

1. You may be currently running another process with `apt`, if this is the case, you can wait for it to complete, another option is to simply kill the process.
2. A previous process (e.g. when apt was executed in the past) did not delete the lock file, this file would exist in `/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend`, then if there wasn't a process using it at all, you would have to remove it manually with `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend`, then force package reconfiguration with `sudo dpkg --configure -a`